TriggerDagRunOperator в airflow не вызывает второй dag
Всем привет. Я недавно еще прочел про
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator, при успешном выполнении одного дага, должен запуститься другой.
есть даг
with DAG(
        'delete_customer_retention',
        default_args=args,
        description='delete customer retention before insert',
        catchup=True,
        start_date=datetime(2024,5,26),
        #end_date=datetime.today(),
) as dag_delete_customer_retention:
    
    delete_customer_retention= PostgresOperator(
    task_id='create',
    postgres_conn_id=postgres_conn_id,
    sql='drop table if exists mart.customer_retention CASCADE;'
    )

    trigger_d=TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='triger',
        trigger_dag_id='sales_mart'
    )

    delete_customer_retention >> trigger_d 

по идее , после выполнения delete_customer_retention должен выполняться dag 'sales_mart' , но появляется картинка, где даг с удалением сработал, а второй находится в статусе - queued, дальше никаких движений по статусам не происходит ... Что я делаю не так?
Настройки дага sales_mart
with DAG(
        'sales_mart',
        default_args=args,
        description='Provide default dag for sprint3',
        catchup=True,
        schedule_interval=None,
        start_date=datetime.today() - timedelta(days=7),
        end_date=datetime.today() + timedelta(days=1),
) as dag

